# jQuery: looping through form based on tabindex?

Tags: jquery, forms, loops, tabindex

So, I have an array, and I want to populate a form, but I want to loop through the form elements based on the **specified** tabindex, not necessarily based on the order in which they appear.

Will jQuery do this natively, or is there a way I can specify this behaviour?

FWIW, I plan on using an .each() on the input's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your array and select the form elements based on their `tabindex` attributes:

```
$.each(values, function (idx, value) {
    $('#myform input[tabindex="' + idx + '"]').val(value);
});
```

*(Offset the idx variable if necessary)*

Alternatively, if you want to select the input elements in one swoop:

```
$("#myform input").each(function () {
    var $input = $(this);
    $input.val(values[$input.attr("tabindex")]);
});
```